# Fundamental group of Klein Bottle from $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Klein Bottle $K$ is [homotopy equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366199/show-a-subspace-formed-by-a-klein-bottle-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-s1-vee-s1) to

$S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$.

Intuitively then $\pi_1(K) \cong \langle c,d \rangle$. However this is wrong, because

$\pi_1(K) \cong \langle c,d \rangle/cdc^{-1}d$.

> Can anybody explain why this intuition fails? Thanks.

I can't understand why homotopy equivalence does not preserve the homotopy group? I would like to see an intuitive explanation, not based on abstract reasoning.

Comment: To my mind, intuitive explanations are usually somewhat abstract. Of course, abstract reasonings can be quite unintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your link again. They're saying that a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (formed by a non-injective continuous image of $K$) is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$, not $K$ itself.

Comment: I see. So homotopy equivalence of an injective image of a space always preserves its homotopy groups?

Comment: Not necessarily. There is an injective map $[0,1) \to S^1$ which is also surjective, hence the image has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But $[0,1)$ is not a topological space. By a space I meant a topological space, sorry for confusion.

Comment: $[0,1)$ is certainly a topological space, given by the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance).

Comment: $[0,1)$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S_1$. $[0,1)$ is contractable to a point, and $S_1$ is not. So I can't understand how this qualifies as an example.

Comment: Sorry I missed the extra condition. Homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups as long as the equivalence preserves the path components of the respective base points.

Comment: This answer was very useful, it clarified a lot of points. Thanks a lot.